# Drawing line on ggmap plot between two countries using long/lat

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap, rworldmap

I am a total newbie to `R` and I would like to draw a line (possibly weighted, e.g., by the number of trips made) between two  countries. Currently, I use longitude and latitude for each capital to draw a line, but I would like to do it using the package ggmap. I was looking around, but did not find any solution so far. I would appreciate a quick help.

```
    require(ggmap)
    require (rworldmap)

    all_content = readLines("ext_lt_intratrd_1_Data.csv")
    skip_second = all_content[-2]
    dat = read.csv(textConnection(skip_second), header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors =F)
    dat[5,2]<- c("Germany") # using a data where the first line is
                             header, but second line must be skipped as it is EU 27
                             and not a single country
    europe <- read.csv("eulonglat.csv", header = TRUE) # using world capitals to 
    generate points
    myfulldata <- merge(dat, europe)
    map <- get_map(location = 'Europe', zoom = 4)
    mapPoints <- ggmap(map) + geom_point(aes(x = UNc_longitude, y = UNc_latitude, size 
    = log(myfulldata$Value)), data = myfulldata, col = "red", alpha= 0.5) # this can 
    be plotted
    # i would continue with drawing line and i searched for references
    # i found arrows(42.66,23.34,50.82,4.47) - which did not work 
    # i tried to look for a reference work more, but could not find
    # instead i found it using with the package rworldmap the following
   lines(c(4.47, 23.32), c(50.82, 42.66))
    # this does not work on ggmap
```

Comment: Sorry, I hope it is fine now...I had to sleep by that time.

Comment: In order to help, I would need links to `ext_lt_intrad_1_Data.csv` and `eulonglat.csv`. Could you put them online somewhere (Dropbox?) and post a link? Alternatively, could you paste a short but representative subset of `myfulldata` into your question?

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19621057/plotting-great-circle-paths/19695755#19695755) draws weighted lines between countries using `rworldmap` with the option for great circles or straight lines. It doesn't, however, use `ggmap`. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. Let me add here the links to the tiny files. http://bianchery.com/rodata/eulonglat.csv respectively .../ext_lt_intrad_1_Data.csv

Comment: My target was to use arrows from one country to to the top 5 trading partners weighted by the road freight volume (e.g. export). But the first step was just to try to find the way to use lines. Is there anybody who is familiar with the topic?