# R: creating a world network map

Tags: r, rworldmap

I would like to produce a world network map in R similar to [the one below from this page](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/wonkblog/wp/2015/09/24/china-explained-simply-with-charts/#901cb659be).

[image]

I have been looking for an R package that will allow me to do this but I have not been able to find one. There is [D3 JavaScript Network Graphs from R](http://christophergandrud.github.io/networkD3/) but I could not find a world network map example.
How can I create something similar in R?

Comment: This post from a while ago does something similar : http://stackoverflow.com/a/19695755/1718356

Comment: Where would be the best place to post for help on this?

Answer (score 6):

Well, FWIW: here's one quick&dirty way to plot vertices ("cities") on a map and connect the edges between vertices with arrows:

```
library(maps)
library(diagram)  
library(plotrix)
palette(rainbow(20))
data("world.cities")

pdf(tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".pdf"), width = 40, height = 20)

map('world', fill = TRUE, col = "lightgray", mar = rep(0, 4)) 

nodes <- transform(with(world.cities, world.cities[pop > 5e6,]), country.etc = as.factor(country.etc))
with(nodes, points(long, lat, col=country.etc, pch=19, cex=rescale(pop, c(1, 8)))) 

set.seed(1)
edges <- subset(data.frame(from = sample(nodes$name, 20, replace = TRUE), to = sample(nodes$name, 20, replace = TRUE), stringsAsFactors = F), from != to)
edges <- merge(merge(edges, nodes[, c("name", "long", "lat")], by.x = "from", by.y = "name"), nodes[, c("name", "long", "lat")], by.x = "to", by.y = "name")
edges$col <- as.integer(nodes$country.etc[match(edges$from, nodes$name)])

apply(edges[, -(1:2)], 1, function(x) curvedarrow(to=x[3:4], from=x[1:2], lcol=x[5], curve=.1, arr.pos = 1, lwd=.5))

dev.off()         
shell.exec(tf)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution using the `geosphere` and `maps` package.
Using the `gcIntermediate` function you can "intermediate points on a great circle inbetween the two points used to define the great circle."

**Here is an example showing flight conncetions from the JKF airport (sample data from the `nycflights13` package filtered with `dplyr`):**

```
library(maps)
library(geosphere)
library(dplyr)
library(nycflights13)


usairports <- filter(airports, lat < 48.5)
usairports <- filter(usairports, lon > -130)
usairports <- filter(usairports, faa!="JFK")
jfk <- filter(airports, faa=="JFK")

map("world", regions=c("usa"), fill=T, col="grey8", bg="grey15", ylim=c(21.0,50.0), xlim=c(-130.0,-65.0))


for (i in (1:dim(usairports)[1])) { 

inter <- gcIntermediate(c(jfk$lon[1], jfk$lat[1]), c(usairports$lon[i], usairports$lat[i]), n=200)

lines(inter, lwd=0.1, col="turquoise2")    
}

points(usairports$lon,usairports$lat, pch=3, cex=0.1, col="chocolate1")
```

[image]

This is based on a tutorial posted on my [blog](http://www.gis-blog.com/flight-connection-map-with-r/).

Comment: You can also check ggnetwork: https://github.com/briatte/ggnetwork/issues/48